# How to print variables depending on an operator in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a simple calculator but I am having a problem. I can't seem to add, subtract, multiply, or divide two variables and print them. I am trying to code so the user can input the numbers along with the operator. Any ideas?

Thanks,

SanguineL

```
number1 = raw_input ("What is the first number?")
operator = raw_input ("What is the operator?")
number2 = raw_input ("What is the second number?")

elif operator == +
    answer = number1 + number2
elif operator == -
    answer = number1 - number2
elif operator == *
    answer = number1 * number2
elif operator == /
    answer = number1 / number2
print answer
```

Comment: This is not at all valid python code. Please to a basic python tutorial first.

Comment: I assume the error you get when you run your program is a syntax error, and you need help fixing that? Or are you asking about something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish the *string* you get from `raw_input` from the *function* an operator represents.

```
if operator == "+":
    answer = number1 + number2
elif ...
```

The `operator` module lets you build a dictionary that abstracts away the lookup process:

```
import operator
number1 = raw_input ("What is the first number?")
op = raw_input ("What is the operator?")
number2 = raw_input ("What is the second number?")
funcs = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul, "/": operator.div}

try:
    f = funcs[op]
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError("Undefined operator %s" % (op,))
answer = f(number1, number2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what does `raw_input ("What is the first number?")` mean (assume that is some kind of form input or sdt_in), but lower part might be (don't forget to convert your inputs like this `number1 = int(number1)`):

```
if operator == '+'
    answer = number1 + number2
elif operator == '-'
    answer = number1 - number2
elif operator == '*'
    answer = number1 * number2
elif operator == '/'
    answer = number1 / number2
print(answer)
```

Comment: `raw_input` was the function in Python 2 that was replaced by `input` in Python 3.

Comment: ah, ok, never used Python 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple issues with your code, the first issue is that `raw_input` will always assume the input is a string and so your number1, operator, and number2 objects will be strings (and I assume you only want the operator variable to be a string). If you want to convert your numbers to floats, then you need to write something like `number1 = float(raw_input ("What is the first number?"))`

The second issue is that you need to start an `if` block with an `if` statement not an `elif` statement. `elif` statements come only after the `if` statement since it stands for "else if" - i.e. in the form if something else if something.

The third issue is that you didn't put quotes around your operators in your conditional statements. Python will not automatically assume they are strings. Python will assume they are variables which you haven't declared yet. You should have a statement like `elif operator == '-'` in order to make the comparison valid.

The fourth and last issue (that I see) is that since you are using `raw_input` it appears you are using python 2. Python 2 has a weird behavior when using the division operator `/` - namely it floors the division if the inputs to it are `ints` or `longs`. That behavior can cause a lot of headaches if you are not aware of it. You should probably include a `from __future__ import division` line at the beginning of your code so dividing doesn't floor the answer.